# http-client - clients uncommonly get sslv3 alert handshake failure

Tags: symfony, symfony-http-client

http-client version 6.3.

Requests to API server are run from another server.. Both running Symfony. So there is no direct call to API from the browser and old browser is not an issue here since the call is made from server to server. Now the default crypto_method on http-client is set to TLS 1.2. Any ideas how these handshake errors can occur?

Majority of other requests are working fine, these handshake failures occur only once an hour or so. They affect random users and do not seem to be tied to a specific API endpoint.

Comment: it can occur due to multiple reasons like incompatible SSL/TLS versions firewall or security restrictions

Comment: I am aware of these possible reasons, but what concerns me most is that these errors occur only for very limited amount of users. It occurs only once or twice in an hour.